# How would I use Schema to mark-up a landing page that has reviews and prices for a product that can be customised?

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

How would I use Schema to mark-up a landing page that has reviews and prices for a product that can be customised?

I originally used product but I just got a manual action for spammy schema.
I am trying to receive stars for this page but if Google doesn't class it as a product page what can I do?

Edit: I have done some more research, could I use the AggregateRating instead? should this be used under the website type or on it's own?

Comment: What does it mean that the product can be "customized"?    The user can choose options such as color and add-ons?      If that is the case, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be still considered a product page.   There must be something more to your manual spam action.

Comment: So, you can't buy anything on this page. this page shows all the prices of the product and then the use can continue to add art or photos to the product.
I think that aggregateReviews are best to use but I don't know how to mark up the reviews on the page if not product or localBusiness